# Can't use whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

When I try to use command:

```
ruby schedule.rb
```

I got error: `config/schedule.rb:1:in '<main>': undefined method 'day' for 1:Integer (NoMethodError)`

my schedule.rb file

```
every 1.day, at: '4:30 pm' do
  runner "CourseHelper.check_valid_date_run"
end
```

Comment: Are you using it in combination with Rails? Do you have a gemfile or how did you install whenever?

Comment: Yes i use it with rails. I wrote gem 'whenever', require: false' in my GemFile, and entered the following commands: bundle install, wheneverize

Comment: How do you run the schedule? With `ruby schedule.rb` or `bundle exec ruby schedule.rb`?

Comment: first, but 2nd give me the same error

Comment: What is the content of you `schedule.rb`

Comment: every 1.day, at: '4:30 pm' 
    do 
    runner "CourseHelper.check_valid_date_run" 
    end

Comment: You should run it with `bundle exec whenever`